# Is there a mechanism to prevent a door from closing violently?

Tags: doors

The door is heavy and people usually put a lot of force to close it, resulting in a violent shock, and the noise that comes with it.  Is there a way to prevent the shock, without having a door that is hard to move. I was thinking of something like a door closer, but I don't want the door to resist when it's fully open.

Is there something to would put a certain amount of resistance when the door is ajar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they tend to just be called Door Closers. They have a spring and a damper (oil or pneumatic) to slow the closing. They look like this:

[image]

Taken from http://www.doorstuff.co.uk/door-closers.php

Comment: Some of these also have the ability stay fully open, preventing the closer from engaging. Once you close it a bit, the closer will close it all the way.